How to allow traffic from VPN to access external Load Balancer (AWS)?
I have configured the aws client vpn and I Modified the security group associated with the external load balancer to allow inbound traffic from the VPN connection's CIDR block.
I am trying to access the load balancer while I am connected to vpn but it's not working
I am able to access the other private resources like ec2 instance.
Is there a way how to resolve this? If so, how?

fyi this is off-topic here as it's not a programming question. Probably better to ask on [sf] - just be sure to provide a [mcve] with all details.
